# How to scrape followers of instagram account with node.js, cheerio and InstAuto/Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, jquery, puppeteer, instagram, cheerio

I'm trying to make a program that creates list of certain user follows and vice versa. After Instagram graph api shut down it became a hard task. I got to a point in which I have a correct div selected, but the javascript command just somehow doesn't work. The exact same command inserted in browser console gives a nice array, but here - undefined, no matter which metod I use: cheerio and jquery or vanilla js with document.queryAll. Can you help me out?
Code:

```
//scrape followers
    await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/fabiawdizlu/followers/');
    await waitFor(5000);
    const html2 = await page.content();
    await waitFor(5000);
    const $2 = cheerio.load(html2);
    const followersList2 = $2('._aacl._aaco._aacw._adda._aacx._aad7._aade').eq(0).text();
    console.log(followersList2);
    const follow3 = page.evaluate(() => {
      var f3 = document.querySelectorAll('_aacl _aaco _aacw _adda _aacx _aad7 _aade')[0];
      return f3;
    }).then((f3) => {
      // console.log(f3.eq(1).text());
      // console.log(f3.eq(2).text());
      // console.log(f3.eq(3).text());
      // console.log(f3.eq(4).text());
      console.log(f3)
      // for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      //   console.log(f3[i].innerText);
      // }
    })
```

This above is one of many methods I tried. For loop doesn't work, jquery's/cheerio eq(i) doesn't work (it displays user of particular id, but doesn't give me array as I want), page evaluate doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, it's my second node project.

Thanks for your time, cheers,
Maciej

Answer (score 0):

With cheerio you can't execute javascript. I think you should use playwright, this will execute javascript and load data dynamically.